# Could not find or load main class com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

When I try to debug java google app engine application in eclipse , it is not starting and throwing following exception.
Could not find or load main class com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain

But it is starting when I run/debug as maven build, but this is not hitting the debug points...

Can anyone tell me how to debug google app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case i removing .metadata/.log folder.